# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel, php7, foreach, laravel-7

Por qué me sale ese error al intentar imprimir un Foreach en la vista?

Lo que hice fue pasar la variable `$my_array` a la vista dónde aplico el foreach. (No sé si uno de los problemas sea la función de `parse_str()` (el cual se encarga de separar los parámetros de un string).

**parseController.php**

```
    public function parse(Request $request){
        $string = $request->input("url");
        parse_str($string, $my_array);
        return view('parse', compact('my_array'));
        }
```

En la vista deberia de imprimirlo de esta manera:

```
    <div class="ui secondary segment">
@foreach ($my_array as $key => $value)
  <p class="code">{{ $key }} : {{ $value }}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Error en vista:

> invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Nos ayudaría a tener mejor contexto, que nos expliques que datos llegan a este método y el por que del uso de `parse_str`

Comment: En la entrada `$request->input("url");` se introduce una URL, por ejemplo `https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?imagen=123456&perfil=12345678&encoder=-zMfiy24~~&calidad=1080p` y es almacenada en la variable `$string` para luego pasar por la función `parse_str()` que se encarga de convertir el string en variables, esas variables se almacenará a la variable `$my_array` para imprimir el Array utilizando `foreach`. Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

Comment: `https://sub1_dominio_com/pagina_php?perfil `=> `12345678~`
`imagen` => `123456`
`calidad` => `1080p`
`encoder` => `-zMfiy24~~`

Comment: Es decir tu intención es convertir ese string en un array que posteriormente iterarás en la vista cierto?

Comment: Si, correcto. El código me funciona perfectamente en PHP puro, pero ando migrando a Laravel para trabajar bajo el patrón MVC de Laravel pero en vista de que el Framework cambia un poco la sintaxis puede que haya algún detalle del que no me he percatado.